# Grouping in drop-down

Tags: usability, forms, user-expectation

[image]

In the above image, I have a drop-down where values are grouped. When I select the value from the list then drop down should display values as c1 or c2?

Comment: What are the cons of not showing the group? You could also use a color scheme to encode that.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the content. Here are some considerations:

- group name is only a visual clue to find a value easier, and the group is commonly known by the users --> don't show the group name
- group name is essential to understand the value (e.g. two identical values that can be used differently cars > golf or sports > golf) you defenitly need to show both
- group names are not commonly known by the users --> you should consider not to group the values because there is not additional help to the user

Comment: In my example all the group heading is different.

Comment: In terms of usability which option works better? To show group name > Options or only option?

Comment: If possible, see my answer, I would prefer to show only the value. There are two reasons: The Value alone is easier to read (shorter) means less cognitive work for the user and secondly depending on groupname and values the entries could be very long so that they need to be cut off which means, the user can not see the chosen value.

Answer (score 1):

If the top level category still bears importance then I'd go for C1. Similar to a breadcrumb on an ecommerce site. Some users may prefer this option as it provides a little more information.

If the drop down is simply to pick a single item to carry onto the next step of the journey then C2 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

As per the website, I have gone through I found out they do not show the main group heading.

For reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#examples

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/grouping

Answer (score 0):

**Tomato is a fruit**

Could you use something other than a dropdown? If something is in the wrong place it's going to be hard to find it..

Comment: The difference between knowledge and wisdom - knowledge is knowing a tomato is a fruit, wisdom is knowing not to put it in a fruit salad :)

Comment: But that's my favorite fruit salad! It's called "salsa" :)